# Timestamp as UTC Integer

Tags: c#, utc

I Have a legacy database with a field containing an integer representing a datetime in UTC

From the documentation:
"Timestamps within a CDR appear in Universal Coordinated Time (UTC). This value remains
independent of daylight saving time changes"

An example of a value is 1236772829.

My question is what is the best way to convert it to a .NET DateTime (in CLR code, not in the DB), both as the UTC value and as a local time value.

Have tried to google it but without any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling that exact phrase gives me [this Cicso page](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/service/7_0_1/cdr-defs/cdrcallinfo.html), which goes on to say "The field specifies a time_t value that is obtained from the operating system. "

[time_t](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_t) is a C library concept which strictly speaking doesn't have to be any particular implementation, but *typically* for UNIX-y systems will be the number of seconds since the start of the Unix epoch, 1970 January 1 00:00.

Assuming this to be right, this code will give you a DateTime from an int:

```
        DateTime epochStart = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

        int cdrTimestamp = 1236772829;

        DateTime result = epochStart.AddSeconds(cdrTimestamp);

        // Now result is 2009 March 11 12:00:29
```

You should sanity check the results you get to confirm that this is the correct interpretation of these `time_t`s.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to know what the integer really means. This will typically consist of:

- An epoch/offset (i.e. what 0 means) - for example "midnight Jan 1st 1970"
- A scale, e.g. seconds, milliseconds, ticks.

If you can get two values and what they mean in terms of UTC, the rest should be easy. The simplest way would probably be to have a `DateTime` (or `DateTimeOffset`) as the epoch, then construct a `TimeSpan` from the integer, e.g. `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds` etc. Add the two together and you're done. EDIT: Using `AddSeconds` or `AddMilliseconds` as per [aakashm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642123/timestamp-as-utc-integer/642161#642161) is a simpler way of doing this bit :)

Alternatively, do the arithmetic yourself and call the [`DateTime` constructor which takes a number of ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx). (Arguably the version taking a `DateTimeKind` as well would be better, so you can explicitly state that it's UTC.)

Comment: You could also guess that @Jon's example is correct and see if your dates make sense if measured as an offset from from 1/1/1970.  I'm guessing they do.